# Trying to make a discord bot that repeats a user's input using tHiS fOnT

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

As the title says, trying to make a discord bot that repeats a certain user's input with every other letter capitalized. Currently having trouble as toString(). At both instances of:
dummy = mockbotString[i].toString();
I am given an error return of "Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined". I'm assuming this has something to do with the array index having null contents.

```js
if(message.author.id == "*************"){
    var mockbotString = new Array(message.content.split());
    for(i=0;i<message.content.length;i++)
    {
        message.channel.send(message.content.length);
        message.channel.send(i);
        if(i%2==0)
        {
            var dummy;
            dummy = mockbotString[i].toString();
            dummy = dummy.toLowerCase();
            mockbotString[i] = dummy;
        }
        else{
            var dummy;
            dummy = mockbotString[i].toString();
            dummy = dummy.toUpperCase();
            mockbotString[i] = dummy;
        }
    }
    message.channel.send(mockbotString);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be as simple as:

```js
var message = {author: 'Someone', content: 'Silly message string.'};

var mockbotString = [...message.content]
    .reduce((r, l, i) => r + l[`to${i%2? 'Lower' : 'Upper'}Case`](), '');

console.log(mockbotString)
```